# Shortcode Error When Calling Custom Attachment

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a shortcode, everything works well apart from one section:

```
    $pdflink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
    $pdf = $pdflink['url'];
```

For some reason when I call $pdf I get an error (Illegal string offset 'url') I'm using similar code in a page template but now I want it to be a shortcode so I can use it elsewhere.

```
function quick_info_shorty( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 17      // Add the *default category id
    ), $atts ) );

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'casestudy',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'cat'       => $id,
    ) );

    $return = '';
    $return .= '<div class="row text-center">';

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $imageid = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
        $featimage = $imageid['0'];
        $pdftitle = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $pdflink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true );
        $pdf = $pdflink['url'];

        $return .= '<div class="col-md-4 grey_bg">
        <a href="' . $pdf . '" target="_blank"><h2>' . $pdftitle . '</h2></a>
        <a href="' . $pdf . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $featimage . '" /></a>
        </div>';
    } 

$return .= '</div>';
return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'case_studies', 'quick_info_shorty' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_ID()` can only be used in a Loop, so use `$post->ID` instead

`$pdflink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wp_custom_attachment', true );`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdflink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', fasle );
    $pdf = $pdflink['url'];
```

Set the $single to true if you want single value as return and to false if your result is array

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/